# Ruby datetime suitable for mysql comparison

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

Rails has been good with automatically inserting correctly formatted datetimes in MySql without the need for me to give it much thought.

However, for doing a validation, I need to check if a stored mysql datetime value (ie 2008-07-02 18:00:00) is greater than or less than "now". I can call `DateTime.now` or `Time.now` but how can I convert that into the format mysql likes?

Thanks

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can use `to_s(:db)` to convert into a database friendly format.

```
Time.now.to_s(:db)
```

However, be careful if you have a timezone specified in Rails because the time will be stored in UTC in the database. You'll need to specify that to do proper comparisons.

```
Time.now.utc.to_s(:db)
```

You can also use `NOW()` function in MySQL instead of generating the current time in Ruby.

Comment: thanks. its awesome to have the railscasts guy answer your questions :)

Comment: This should really be a method in rails!

Comment: 100 thanks. This answer just reminded me of NOW()'s existence. ActiveRecord sure has spoilt me. I've been passing Time.now since I hardly touch SQL anymore. Gone are the days of hand-tweaking SQL (at least for me).

Comment: perfect! Thanks for the solution @ryanb! And railscasts is the best!

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I needed! Seems like the discrepancy is from SQL's lack of ISO 8061 compliance, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx Re: SQL "datetime is not ANSI or ISO 8601 compliant."

Comment: This didn't quite work for me. I had to use `ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(time)` to get the format I needed. (requires ActiveRecord of course, so mostly applies to Rails)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to.  Let Rails do the work for you:

If your model is `Widget` this will find all the widgets that have been created in the last day:

```
Thing.find(:all, :condition => ["created_at > ?", Time.now - 1.day])
```

Rails will automatically convert the timestamp into the correct format.

Comment: thanks for the response but this doesn't fit my use case. I already have my object retrieved from the DB. Long after it is retrieved, I need to run a time-based validation on it so the check has to be done in Ruby code and not in a query. Thanks again though.

Comment: I had a different scenario, and this worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: In Rails 4+ just use `Thing.where('created_at > ?', 6.months.ago)`

Comment: Just to note the above comment `6.months.ago` and the original suggestion with `Time.now - 1.day` are also different as they use different reference times potentially.  Time.now uses system time, which may not be what the `.ago` compares to depends on app config, TZ env var etc