# Converting Time or DateTime to MySQL compatible DATETIME

Tags: mysql, ruby, datetime

According to "[Ruby datetime suitable for mysql comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255983/ruby-datetime-suitable-for-mysql-comparison)", I should be able to do:

```
Time.now.to_s(:db)
```

This doesn't appear to be valid anymore. I get:

```
irb(main):001:0> Time.now.to_s(:db)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
        from (irb):1:in `to_s'
        from (irb):1
        from C:/Ruby22/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Does this functionality still exist or do I have to manually format the date and time to fit MySQL format?

I'm using ruby 2.2.2.

Comment: The above works in Rails, but not pure Ruby. Are you in Rails?

Comment: Nope, I'm using plain ruby.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Time#to_s` doesn't accept arguments in Ruby. If you're using Rails, ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone supplies the `to_s` method you were referring to.

To get this format in Ruby without ActiveSupport you can use:

```
Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: You might also try `Time.now.iso8601` which your DB should recognize.

Comment: A default MySQL instance on Google Cloud Platform with default Rails created_at and updated_at timestamps does not support iso8601.