# ActiveRecord Displays Time as DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a DB field of type `time`
The field stores just the time in the DB.
When the field value is read with ActiveRecord in Rails 4.2 I get a dateTime value instead. Eg.:

`08:30:00` in the database becomes `2000-01-01 08:30:00`

Is this the expected behavior with AR?

Comment: Yes, but you can use the method strftime to format the date. Ex: Yourfield.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

Comment: Yes it is. There is nu such time as just time without date in the db.

Comment: @developer033 I do use strftime, just wanted to make sure this is expected behavior
@BroiSatse Postgres does have a `time` type

Answer (score -1):

The database always stores these values. You can modify it though by using time.to_s(:db).

look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1256014/4192210)

Answer (score -1):

There is no data format in MySQL which will save just the Time: it must have a date attached in order to be useful.

If you plan to get on the HH:MM:SS format,

please use rails function such as **strftime("HH:MM:SS")**...

additional info like:
***to_time**
***to_date**